# combine two value of array in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Example, i have an array :

```
a = [2 3 1 2 4 5 6 4];
b = sort(a);
b = [1 2 2 3 4 4 5 6];
```

Now i want to combine two value of a and b :

```
c = [21 32 12 23 44 54 65 46]
```

then i do the sort of c :

```
d = [12 21 23 32 44 46 54 65]
```

and i combine again from c and d (first of c, same value of second c and first d, last d) :

```
e = [212 321 123 232 444 546 654 465]
```

then i do the sort of e :

```
f = [123 212 232 321 444 465 546 654]
```

and i combine again from e and f :

```
g = [2123 3212 1232 2321 4444 5465 6546 4654]
```

so on till the length of a that equals to 8.

Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
a = [2 3 1 2 4 5 6 4]
for m=2:8
    b = sort(a)
    t = round(b-10*floor(b/10))
    a = 10*a+t
end
```

It looks to me like the algorithm just adds the last digit of each sorted list onto the corresponding number in the unsorted list. `t` is just the last digit in `b`, then `10*a+t` shifts the existing digits in `a` and puts `t` at the end. Apologies if I have misunderstood the objective and this is the wrong algorithm, but it works with you example. I guess you will need to convince yourself whether the code does follow your rules.